# How do I send emails from another outlook mailbox (non-primary) in Python using win 32?

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook

I have the following code but it throws an error TypeError: 'Accounts' object is not iterable

import win32com.client as win32

def send_mail():
outlook_app = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

```
print('email_Sent')

mail_item = outlook_app.CreateItem(0)   # 0: olMailItem

send_account = None
for i in range(1, outlook_app.Session.Accounts.Count + 1):
    account = outlook_app.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
    if account.DisplayName == 'SECONDAY_EXCHANGE_ACCOUNT':
        send_account = account
    break

mail_item.To = 'RECIPIENT'
mail_item.Subject = 'Test sending using particular account'
mail_item.BodyFormat = 2   # 2: Html format
mail_item.HTMLBody = '''
    <H2>Hello, This is a test mail.</H2>
    Hello Guys. 
    '''

mail_item.Send()
```

I changed the code based on below suggestions. But it just exits out giving no error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if it is a delegate mailbox rather than a separate Exchange account, it won't be in the `Namespace.Accounts` collection. All you need to do is set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property to the name of the user who owns the delegare mailbox.

If it **is** a separate Exchange account in your profile and you do need to set the `MailItem.Account` property, iterate through the accounts using an indexed "for" loop (from 1 to Count).

```py
send_account = None
for i in range(1, outlook_app.Session.Accounts.Count + 1):
    account = outlook_app.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
    if account.DisplayName == 'SHARED_MAILBOX_NAME':
        send_account = account
        break
```

Comment: It is a separate exchange account which is a shared mailbox. All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: A shared mailbox is shown alongside the primary mailbox. A separate Exchange account cannot consist of a shared mailbox only - it is always the primary mailbox and zero or more delegate mailboxes. You can have secondary Exchange accounts. Is that what you mean?
Do you see the mailbox in question in File | Account Settings | Email? Or only when you double click on the Exchange account to open it, More Settings | Advanced | Open these additional mailboxes?

Comment: Yes I do see it as a microsoft exchange account. It is a secondary Exchange account. confirmed

Comment: Then you need to set the Account property. See the updated answer above

Comment: I changed the code to the above post per your suggestion. This time it just exits out of the code and does nothing.

Comment: Did you step through your code? Does it not find the right account? Is the name what you expect it to be? Did you check that the `Account` object has the right value of the `DisplayName` property?